# Llamar API publicada en net core

Tags: api, asp.net-core

estoy desarrollando un sitio web que llama a una api que he desarrollado en otro proyecto.
En un proyecto he desarrollado una API, si la llamo desde el mismo proyecto, sí funciona.
En otro proyecto donde estoy desarrollando el sitio web, cuando llamo a la api que he publicado en internet, simplemente no la llama.
No se donde estaria el error, comparto el código correspondiente

Archivo js

```
    const uri = "http://alexistm-001-site1.atempurl.com/api/movies/";
//const uri = 'api/movies';
let todos = [];

function getMovies() {
    fetch(uri)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => _displayItems(data))
        .catch(error => console.error('Unable to get items.', error));
}

function _displayItems(data) {
    const tBody = document.getElementById('todos');
    tBody.innerHTML = '';

    _displayCount(data.length);

    const button = document.createElement('button');

    data.forEach(item => {
        let isCompleteCheckbox = document.createElement('input');
        isCompleteCheckbox.type = 'checkbox';
        isCompleteCheckbox.disabled = true;
        isCompleteCheckbox.checked = item.isComplete;

        let editButton = button.cloneNode(false);
        editButton.innerText = 'Edit';
        editButton.setAttribute('onclick', `displayEditForm(${item.id})`);

        let deleteButton = button.cloneNode(false);
        deleteButton.innerText = 'Delete';
        deleteButton.setAttribute('onclick', `deleteMovie(${item.id})`);

        let tr = tBody.insertRow();

        let td1 = tr.insertCell(0);
        td1.appendChild(isCompleteCheckbox);

        let td2 = tr.insertCell(1);
        let textNode = document.createTextNode(item.title);
        td2.appendChild(textNode);

        let td3 = tr.insertCell(2);
        let textNode1 = document.createTextNode(item.genre);
        td3.appendChild(textNode1);

        let td4 = tr.insertCell(3);
        let textNode2 = document.createTextNode(item.rating);
        td4.appendChild(textNode2);

        let td5 = tr.insertCell(4);
        td5.appendChild(editButton);

        let td6 = tr.insertCell(5);
        td6.appendChild(deleteButton);

        //let td5 = tr.insertCell(4);
        //td5.appendChild(deleteButton);
    });

    todos = data;
}
```

Codigo CSHTML

```
 @page
@model CursosModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Cursos";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<body>
    <h1>To-do CRUD</h1>
    <h3>Add</h3>
    <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" onsubmit="addMovie()">
        <input type="text" id="add-title" placeholder="New to-do">
        <input type="text" id="add-genre" placeholder="New to-do">
        <input type="text" id="add-rating" placeholder="New to-do">
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>

    <div id="editForm">
        <h3>Edit</h3>
        <form action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="updateMovie()">
            <input type="hidden" id="edit-id">
            <input type="checkbox" id="edit-isComplete">
            <input type="text" id="edit-title">
            <input type="text" id="edit-genre">
            <input type="text" id="edit-rating">
            <input type="submit" value="Save">
            <a onclick="closeInput()" aria-label="Close">&#10006;</a>
        </form>
    </div>

    <p id="counter"></p>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Is Complete?</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="todos"></tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        getMovies();
    </script>
</body>
```

Ya coloqué en el archivo startup.cs

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Y no me muestra la data en el archivo cshtml

Agradeciendo su valiosa ayuda. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Bueno para fines que nos pueda ayudar, aparentemente el error es porque estoy llamando a un link sin el protocolo https, entonces para descartar primero si es esto; añadiré un certificado de seguridad en el sitio; y luego volveré a probar el enlace.
actualizaré el post cuando haya probado esta utilidad. Gracias